# ruby on rails prepared statement for oracle view/function

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3, prepared-statement

I have the following  code which executes an oracle view as follows:

```
def run_query
    connection.exec_query(
      "SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_REQRESP(#{type_param},
                                      #{search_type_param},
                                      #{tid_param},
                                      #{last_param},
                                      #{key_param},
                                      #{tran_id_param},
                                      #{num_param},
                                      #{start_date_param},
                                      #{end_date_param}))")
end
```

The output of the above query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_REQRESP('ALL',
 'ALL_TRAN',
 '100007',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 TO_DATE('27-January-2017','dd-MON-yy'),
 TO_DATE('31-January-2017','dd-MON-yy')))
```

The problem is that above query has a SQL injection vulnerability.

So, i tried to add a prepare statement as follows:

```
 connection.exec_query('SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_REQRESP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))','myquery',[type_param,search_type_param,tid_param,last_param,key_param,tran_id_param,num_param,start_date_param,end_date_param])
```

I get the following error now:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for "'ALL'":String: SELECT *
>   FROM TABLE(FN_REQRESP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))

It's the single quotes that messing it up I beleive. Is there a way to overcome this?

EDIT:
I tried NDN's answer and the error below:

```
OCIError: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis: SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_REQRESP('\'ALL\'',
                                      '\'ALL_TRAN\'',
                                      '\'100007\'',
                                      '\'\'',
                                      '\'\'',
                                      '\'\'',
                                      '\'\'',
                                      'TO_DATE(\'01-February-2017\',\'dd-MON-yy\')',
                                      'TO_DATE(\'10-February-2017\',\'dd-MON-yy\')'))
```

Comment: maybe a stupid question, and it is needed for oracle, but have you tried to remove the "[" and "]" ? for me it looks like you try to give the second ? an array, also probably named bind variables would be a good idea here: http://millarian.com/rails/quick-tip-rails-named-bind-variables/

Comment: yes i tried removing the [] and got this
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (11 for 3)

Comment: also I can't used named bind variables since this is an oracle function and I dont know the column names. I know only what params I can pass

Comment: @Michael, you don't need the colum names for that, you just replace a ? with a symbol, for example :type_param. and then instead of passing an array, you pass an hash like { :type_param => type_param, ...} but this is just a tip, it does not solve your problem, but would increase the readability of your code, and i am not 100% certain it works with the oracle adapter

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/8ed51b5c87d6e49eba504f4272d23152f6c417b5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb#L19), `binds` gets cast in some magical way and you have to pass a named `prepare: true` argument as well.

It also used to work differently in [older versions](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rsim/oracle-enhanced/ActiveRecord%2FConnectionAdapters%2FOracleEnhanced%2FDatabaseStatements%3Aexec_query).

---

To save yourself the trouble, you can simply use `#sanitize`:

```
params = {
  type:        type_param,
  search_type: search_type_param,
  tid:         tid_param,
  last:        last_param,
  key:         key_param,
  tran_id:     tran_id_param,
  num:         num_param,
  start_date:  start_date_param,
  end_date:    end_date_param,
}

params.each do |key, param|
  params[key] = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(param)
end

connection.exec_query(
  "SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_REQRESP(#{params[:type]},
                                  #{params[:search_type]},
                                  #{params[:tid]},
                                  #{params[:last]},
                                  #{params[:key]},
                                  #{params[:tran_id]},
                                  #{params[:num]},
                                  #{params[:start_date]},
                                  #{params[:end_date]}))"
)
```

Comment: ndn, I tried your solution but got an error. See up EDIT to original post at the bottom for the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Prepared Statement. In [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) you can find an example how to use it.

Comment: I don't see how i can use the prepared statement syntax in my example.